# IOException deleting files used attachments in MailMessage

Tags: c#, email, attachment

i am using visual studios 2010 with .NET 4.0.

i am attaching files from my local hard drive to a MailMessage (i.e. `MailMessage.Attachements.Add(Attachment))`. after i execute the `SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage)` command, i iterate over the attachment paths and perform a `File.Delete(string path)`. however, i immediately get a `System.IO.IOException`.

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'c:\temp\test.docx' because it is being used by another another process.
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
>      ...

i thought that maybe i couldn't delete large files because it was still being streamed during the `SmtpClient.Send` command. however, this seemingly happens for files of all sizes (2 KB to 8 MB). can someone please clarify what is going on?

is there a way to make sure the `SmtpClient.Send` call is complete (it has completely sent the email with the attachments and released all locks on the files/attachments) before i issue a File.Delete call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ensure that the stream that the attachment stream is closed before you delete it.

I suggest wrapping the creation of the new attachment object in a `using` statement to ensure proper disposal before you try to delete the file.

Comment: Also, the MailMessage should be disposed.

Comment: how would a using statement work for multiple attachments? if it was one attachment, that makes sense, but for multiple attachments for each MailMessage, i don't know how that would work. could you please give an example?

Comment: @user373312 - each attachment would be opening a new stream, so you would need to wrap the inclusion of each in a `using` statement. This would best be achieved by wrapping the adding of attachments in a method of its own.

Comment: on your first point, that is precisely my question: how to ensure that the streams are closed?

Comment: @user373312 - That's what the `using` statement will do. It implements the Dispose pattern around the object being newed up.

Comment: @Oded i am probably missing something. what i do is iterate over the attachment paths using a for loop. when i do that, inside the for loop, i have a using statement; example, using(Attachment = new Attachment(path)). but then on SmtpClient.Send, i get a SmtpException because the attachment object has already been disposed.

Comment: @user373312 - In that case, create a `Stream` directly in a `using` statement and create the attachments using that stream (there are overloads that take streams).

Comment: The problem is, when you add the attachments in a for loop and have it in a using, you are disposing the attachments before you send the mail. You must do it after. So, add the attachments without `using`, then call `Send`, then iterate through the attachments collection and call Dispose on each. You should wrap the adding and Send with `try...finally` block and dispose the attachments in the finally block to ensure it will always happen. After that, you should be able to delete the files. Also, don't forget to wrap the MailMessage creation with `using` block to dispose the message itself.

Comment: @Frantisek thank you a million! i can't vote you up b/c i'm a n00b on stackoverflow. your solution worked perfectly! i appreciate your help.

Comment: could someone mark this question as answered? Franktisek's response helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

File this under the better late than never category: I had the same issue, and was able to solve it by simply calling the Dispose() method on the MailMessage instance after sending the message, like so:

```
        try
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add(input.To);
            msg.From = new MailAddress(input.From);
            msg.Subject = input.Subject;
            msg.Body = input.Message;
            Attachment att = new Attachment(reportPath);
            msg.Attachments.Add(att);

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(serverAddress, serverPort);
            client.Credentials = creds;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(msg);
            msg.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SendAsync()` instead. It has a callback when it's completed. In the callback, delete your files.

The callback is `client.SendCompleted` on the `SMPTClient` class.

If nothing else, it may give a clue as to what is going on.

Comment: i followed your lead and the reference at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx. when i used SmtpClient.SendAsync, none of my emails were sent.